How does the law of conservation of energy hold in the case of a simple linear DC machine?
Consider a simple linear DC machine as shown below:

Assume that the linear machine is initially running at the no-load steady-state conditions where the current is 0A, the magnitude of velocity |v| equals VB/Bl and induced voltage eind equals VB. A force Fapp is now applied in the direction of motion. Now there is an acceleration in the direction of motion due to which the velocity increases. This increases eind charging the battery. Since there is a current flowing in the conductor, there will be an induced force Find acting opposite to the direction of applied force Fapp. The system will reach a steady state when |Find| = |Fapp|.
It is given in the book that the mechanical power \$F_{ind}\cdot v\$  is converted to electrical power \$e_{ind}\cdot i\$, but isn't it the power supplied by the external force that is getting converted to electrical power? If this is the case then
$$
F_{app}\cdot v = F_{ind} \cdot v + e_{ind}\cdot i     \tag{1}
$$
After steady state \$|F_{ind}| = |F_{app}|\$,  so eq(1) reduces to
$$ e_{ind} \cdot i = 0, $$
which is not the case. Where is my reasoning going wrong and where does the power supplied by external force go?
Reference: The Linear DC Machine as a Generator, Page 41, Electric Machinery Fundamentals 4e by Stephen J.Chapman

How can a "magnitude of velocity" equal a voltage? That's not possible. The physical entity of "magnitude of velocity" is "distance per time", and of voltage is "distance squared times mass divided by current divided by the third power of time"; that's simply not compatible.

Your units are inconsistent. If $v$ is velocity, then $F_{app} \times v$ is power in Watts. But what is $e_{ind} \times v$? What is voltage times velocity? I think you mean $e_{ind} \times i$, which would also be Watts.

In the case where a force \$F_{app}\$ is being applied to the machine output in the same direction as it is moving, with velocity \$v\$, then there is power delivered to the machine mechanically:
$$ P_M = F_{app} \times v $$
On the electrical side, that same power must be delivered from the machine to the circuitry. In keeping with passive sign convention, where power into a thing is positive, and power out of it is negative, this power is negative:
$$ P_E = -F_{app} \times v $$
It is manifest electrically as current \$i\$ and voltage \$e_{ind}\$, power being their product:
$$ P_E = -i \times e_{ind} $$
Note: the author of the diagram has chosen to have positive current flowing to the left through resistance \$R\$, which does not conform with passive sign convention. Here, a positive current \$i\$ combined with positive EMF \$e_{ind}\$ implies the machine producing electrical power, and battery and resistor receiving it, contrary to passive sign convention. We must take care with the sign of \$i\$.
Both of these expressions for \$P_E\$ have units of Watts, and I believe is where you went wrong. You have somehow conflated current \$i\$ with velocity \$v\$, in your strange term \$e_{ind}\times v\$. That product does not produce Watts, which could have been a big clue.
Equate the two expressions for \$P_E\$, as per conservation of energy:
$$ -F_{app} \times v = -i \times e_{ind} $$
$$ F_{app} \times v = i \times e_{ind} $$
You can then proceed to determine how that power is distributed between \$R\$ and \$V_B\$ using the usual KVL, KCL and Ohm's laws.
